# Test get Skipped if before method failed in child class

Tags: inheritance, testng

I have a `Base` class with all the `TestNg` annotaions where i initialize browser and configuration in `@beforetest` and `@beforeclass` respectively .

I also have `@beforemethod` in test class which extends the base class if `@beforeMethod` in any child class fails all other tests int the other class also get skipped.

Can anyone help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

try to set configfailurepolicy attribute of your suite (testng.xml) to "continue". See testng [dtd](http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd.php)